# deep troubling situation with angular 5 and slow typing into input boxes

Tags: angular

There is a problem that is posing itself as a show-stopper or deal-breaker.
We've completed a web app, using angular 5 & template driven forms where everything works but this one feature is just killing us. It's like a sniper shot.

From time to time, on our laptops and desktops, we experience slow typing into the text fields of our application's input fields. And this happens across the board, ( that is windows, mac, safari, chrome ).

The situation lasts for a while and then it totally goes away! 
During the happening, there is no indication of anything we can detect (other than the symptom itself ). I mean there are no console log errors, no high CPU activity, no nothing!.

The problem is that we simply observe some delay ( up to a second ) in the appearance of the letters we type in, into the textfields and textrea boxes.

How would you debug this situation?

So far, I have applies the following solutions;
spellcheck=no, 
autocapitalize=off 
autocomplete=off 
autocorrect=off 
But this does not put an end to this saga.

I also compile the app using the "ng build --prod" so it is totally optimized.

Are there any other suggestions you can offer?

Here is how a sample textarea HTML is:

```
<textarea placeholder="enter text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"  name="description" [(ngModel)]="learningPlan.description"   maxlength="1500" #local_description="ngModel"></textarea>
```

Is it possible to tell angular to not to do the change detection on these input boxes while typing is going on? I'm running out of options.

There is one possible suggestion in [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6311) whereby someone is suggesting to do this: `@Output() event : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(false);` But it does not say where this line of code is supposed to go in.

Comment: which ide are you using for your code ?

Comment: sometimes this happens when using input listeners, try to reduce those events as much as possible, also if you are using webstorm or intellij you can easily debug your code and see the problem

Comment: We had a similar problem with having a form rendered with `*ngFor`. We had a complex property calculated on ngOnInit and it also manipulated as a side-effect the array for the ngFor. One of our programmers (me) accidentally binded the function in the html instead of the function's initial stored return value ... on every mouse movement it run again, re-rendered the array and slowed the app down considerably.

Comment: Does your textarea contain a large text when you experience the typing lags ? Is it something you could reproduce in a small stackblitz projet ?

Comment: thanks to all, who responded. Hussein: I'm using vs code + angular cli ( latest & greatest ), forestG: I have built a different architecture than the typical angular apps. This may have to do with the issue I am facing but it is hard to tell. A lot of people suffer from this/or very similar problem and this seems to be more of a core-issue that angular needs to fix once and for all. ibenjelloun: It's not possible to produce this cause as I said in the original question, this does not happen all the time. It happens to (say) %10 percent of the time for the same computer. So what did I do?

Comment: I did this: https://toddmotto.com/super-fast-angular-ng-model-options-limit-digest-cycles/   which is as easy as adding this brilliant code and this seems to have taken care of the problem: `ng-model-options="{
    'updateOn': 'default blur',
    'debounce': {
      'default': 250,
      'blur': 0
    }
  }"`

Answer (score 5):

I've found this discussion [ionic issue 10837](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10837) and i've solved with content on [this link](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f).

---

In my case, this problem was visible when i typed inside a modal. So, my code turned into this:

```
constructor(public changeDetection: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

openModal() {
    this.changeDetection.detach();
    //open modal
    modal.callback ( r => {
        this.changeDetection.reattach();
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, this works, even when I have changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush on the class that is calling the dialog this is the solution for sluggish input handling of the components in the modal dialog

Answer (score 3):

Try to use enableProdMode.  enable it by:

```
 import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
 :

 enableProdMode();
 platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue in one of my application where after loading one component all other operations such as entering into input box, opening of dropdown were getting slowed down.

Issue was with one directive where ngAfterContentChecked lifecyle hook was implemented with DOM manipulation for window resize. After removing this application is working fine.
So do not perform any operation inside lifecycle such as ngDoCheck, ngAfterContentChecked, ngAfterViewChecked.