# How can I speed up typing in my textarea with angular mentions autocomplete?

Tags: angular, textarea

Typing in Textarea is too slow

We have a textarea where we have included few events. There is a lag when we type and the letters appearing in the field. Below is my html and I'm using angular mentions(https://www.npmjs.com/package/@flxng/mentions) in text field autocomplete. I doubt it might be because of the events used in this control. But I won't be able to remove any of these.

I noticed similar issue as mentioned in [deep troubling situation with angular 5 and slow typing into input boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787872/deep-troubling-situation-with-angular-5-and-slow-typing-into-input-boxes) but that didn't help me to solve this issue.

Also I tried adding
ng-model-options="{'updateOn': 'default blur','debounce': {'default': 250,'blur': 0}}"
but no luck.

```
<textarea formControlName="textControl" cdkTextareaAutosize #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"     rows="1"
style="margin-left: 10px;font-size: 14px;color:#424242; padding-top: 14px;resize: none;overflow:hidden"
matInput type="search" id="textTextArea" [value]="textInput" #commonSearchString
placeholder="Start" [(ngModel)]="textInput"
(focus)="onfocus()" (itemSelected)="valSelected($event)"></textarea>
```

Comment: **not** use in the same input formControlName and ngModel. You need decided if use ReactiveForms or Template driven Form

Comment: exactly. What you are doing here is basically producing infinite loops, which of course would kill any performance

Comment: Does that mean I can use only one of them. Either formControlName or ngModel?

Comment: @sreeja, yes. When you use [(ngModel)] you're using ["Template driven form"](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) (it's only two ways binding: a variable in .ts show his value in the input and when you change the input the variable in .ts change) When you use formControlName you're using ["Reactive Forms"](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) (you create a formGroup with severals formControls and the value of the formControls is showed in the input and when you change, the value of this FormControl change.

Comment: Thanks for that information. But I'm unable to resolve this issue by removing formControlName or ngModel. The only thing works in performance improvement is removing #commonSearchString and flx-mentions code. But this functionality is necessary to have autocomplete.